# SQL Count distinct rows with their total number of appearance

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am trying to write a big query for google data studio from firebase analytics.
Currently raw data is as follows:

```
No.  |  CHANNEL
---------------
1.   | alpha
2.   | beta
3.   | gamma
4.   | delta
5.   | delta
6.   | alpha
7.   | sigma
8.   | sigma
9.   | sigma
10.  | sigma
```

What I need

```
Channel | hits
---------------
Sigma   | 4
delta   | 2
alpha   | 2
gamma   | 1
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could try this example:

```sql
select channel, count(*) as hits
from <table>
group by channel;
```

This give you a count for all the different channel types.